# How to shuffle questions in an Array

Tags: java, android, arrays

I am new in Android programming, I created a quiz app now I want to shuffle the questions of my Array in a random row. I have a Main Activity and a QuestionLibrary there I have 3 Arrays one for the questions, one for th chices, one for the answers.. Now i want to randomize the question row. How can  do that? i tried several methods with one only Array but it is full of errors... How can i do it? Can you send me the solution with my method-variable names?

QuestionLibrary:

```
private String mChoices[][] = {
        {"1993", "1986", "1967"},
        {"-260", "-272,15", "279,15"},
        {"a plant","The active substance of marijuana" , "a spider"},
        {"6", "10","8"},
        {"12","15","10"},
        {"Uranus","Neptune","Saturn"},
        {"HCl","NaCl","CO"},
        {"John F. Kennedy", "Richard Nixon","James A. Garfield"},
        {"Canada","Denmark", "Greenland is an own state?"},
        {"12","20","14"},
        {"10","12","14"},
        {"not","never","now"},
        {"Leningrad","Wolgograd","Dimitrijgrad"}
};


private String mCorrectAnswers[] = {"1993", "-272,15", "The active substance of marijuana", "8", "12","Uranus","NaCl","John F. Kennedy","Denmark","12","14","not","Wolgograd"};



public String getQuestion (int a){
    String question = mQuestions[a];
    return question;
}

public String getChoice1 (int a){
    String choice0 = mChoices[a][0];
    return choice0;
}

public String getChoice2 (int a) {
    String choice1 = mChoices[a][1];
    return choice1;
}

public String getChoice3 (int a) {
    String choice2 = mChoices [a] [2];
    return choice2;
}

public String getCorrectAnswer (int a){
    String answer = mCorrectAnswers [a];
    return answer;


}


public int getlength() {


    int length = 13;
    return length;
}
```

Main Activity:

```
package amapps.impossiblequiz;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class QuizActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mToggle;
    private Toolbar mToolbar;
    private MenuItem menuItem;
    private Intent in;

    private QuestionLibrary mQuestionLibrary = new QuestionLibrary();

    private TextView mScoreView;
    private TextView mQuestionView;
    private Button mButtonChoice1;
    private Button mButtonChoice2;
    private Button mButtonChoice3;

    private String mAnswer;
    private int mScore = 0;
    private int mQuestionNumber = 0;






    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_quiz);


        mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.nav_action);

        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);

        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);

        mToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, R.string.open, R.string.close);
        mDrawerLayout.addDrawerListener(mToggle);
        mToggle.syncState();
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true); //Able to see the Navigation Burger "Button"


        NavigationView mNavigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nv1);
        mNavigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener(){
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem){
                switch (menuItem.getItemId()){
                    case(R.id.nav_stats):
                        Intent accountActivity = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Menu2.class);
                        startActivity(accountActivity);
                }
                return true;
            }
        });



        mScoreView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.score);
        mQuestionView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.question);
        mButtonChoice1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.choice1);
        mButtonChoice2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.choice2);
        mButtonChoice3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.choice3);


        updateQuestion();

        //Start of Button Listener1
        mButtonChoice1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //My logic for Button goes in here

                if (mButtonChoice1.getText() == mAnswer) {
                    mScore = mScore + 1;
                    updateScore(mScore);
                    updateQuestion();

                    //This line of code is optional...
                    Toast.makeText(QuizActivity.this, "Correct", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(QuizActivity.this, "Wrong... Try again!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    mScore = 0;
                    updateScore(mScore);
                    updateQuestion();

                }
            }


        });
        //End of Button Listener1

        //Start of Button Listener2
        mButtonChoice2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //My logic for Button goes in here

                if (mButtonChoice2.getText() == mAnswer) {
                    mScore = mScore + 1;
                    updateScore(mScore);
                    updateQuestion();

                    //This line of code is optional...
                    Toast.makeText(QuizActivity.this, "Correct", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(QuizActivity.this, "Oh... wrong your score is 0", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    mScore = 0;
                    updateScore(mScore);
                    updateQuestion();

                }
            }


        });
        //End of Button Listener2

        //Start of Button Listener3
        mButtonChoice3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //My logic for Button goes in here

                if (mButtonChoice3.getText() == mAnswer) {
                    mScore = mScore + 1;
                    updateScore(mScore);
                    updateQuestion();

                    //This line of code is optional...
                    Toast.makeText(QuizActivity.this, "Correct", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(QuizActivity.this, "Come on, that was not so hard...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    mScore = 0;
                    updateScore(mScore);
                    updateQuestion();

                }
            }


        });
        //End of Button Listener3

    }

    private void updateQuestion() {

        if (mQuestionNumber < mQuestionLibrary.getlength()) {
            mQuestionView.setText(mQuestionLibrary.getQuestion(mQuestionNumber));
            mButtonChoice1.setText(mQuestionLibrary.getChoice1(mQuestionNumber));
            mButtonChoice2.setText(mQuestionLibrary.getChoice2(mQuestionNumber));
            mButtonChoice3.setText(mQuestionLibrary.getChoice3(mQuestionNumber));

            mAnswer = mQuestionLibrary.getCorrectAnswer(mQuestionNumber);
            mQuestionNumber++;
        } else Toast.makeText(QuizActivity.this, "Last Question!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
    private void updateScore(int point) {
        mScoreView.setText("" + mScore);

    }


    @Override //Makes that the "Burger" Item, shows the Drawer if someone clicks on the simbol
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (mToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't actually see any collection/array containing the questions, but perhaps you could use `Collections.shuffle()` if it were an array of strings.

Answer (score 1):

You should change `QuestionLibrary` class like this.

```
public class QuestionLibrary {

    private final String mChoices[][] = { /* ... */ };
    private final String mQuestions[] = { /* ... */ };
    private final String mCorrectAnswers[] = { /* ... */ };

    private final List<Integer> indexes = new ArrayList<>();

    public QuestionLibrary() {
        for (int i = 0; i < mQuestions.length; ++i)
            indexes.add(i);
    }

    private int index(int i) {
        return indexes.get(i);
    }

    public String getQuestion(int a) {
        return mQuestions[index(a)];
    }

    public String getChoice1(int a) {
        return mChoices[index(a)][0];
    }

    public String getChoice2(int a) {
        return mChoices[index(a)][1];
    }

    public String getChoice3(int a) {
        return mChoices[index(a)][2];
    }

    public String getCorrectAnswer(int a) {
        return mCorrectAnswers[index(a)];
    }

    public int getlength() {
        return mQuestions.length;
    }

    public void shuffle() {
        Collections.shuffle(indexes);
    }
}
```

Then you can shuffle it like this.

```
QuestionLibrary q = new QuestionLibrary();
System.out.printf("Question:0 Choice:(%s, %s, %s) Answer:%s%n",
    q.getChoice1(0), q.getChoice2(0), q.getChoice3(0), q.getCorrectAnswer(0));
q.shuffle();
System.out.printf("Question:0 Choice:(%s, %s, %s) Answer:%s%n",
    q.getChoice1(0), q.getChoice2(0), q.getChoice3(0), q.getCorrectAnswer(0));
```

result:

```
Question:0 Choice:(1993, 1986, 1967) Answer:1993
Question:0 Choice:(-260, -272,15, 279,15) Answer:-272,15
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try it... Do I have to add something in the Main Activity (Quiz Activity)?

Comment: You need to add `mQuestionLibrary.shuffle()` somewhere else.

Comment: Sir where do i have to add this code: QuestionLibrary q = new QuestionLibrary();
System.out.printf("Question:0 Choice:(%s, %s, %s) Answer:%s%n",
    q.getChoice1(0), q.getChoice2(0), q.getChoice3(0), q.getCorrectAnswer(0));
q.shuffle();
System.out.printf("Question:0 Choice:(%s, %s, %s) Answer:%s%n",
    q.getChoice1(0), q.getChoice2(0), q.getChoice3(0), q.getCorrectAnswer(0));

Answer (score 0):

Use a `Random` instance and the `nextInt(int n)` method where `n` is the size of your array.
And repeat the operation to sort all elements of it.

Or better you may use `Collections.shuffle(List<?> list)` if you replace your array by a List.

Comment: If you begin, maybe, you should try to write a code to just sort an array and once it works, integrate this logic in your app. Trying to do all things without understanding basis will not allow you to learn.

Comment: Can you do me a favorte and help me step by step to add on my project the randomer, please?